# Create Custom Memebership Provider in MVC 4 Always get error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I tried to develop custom membership provider in order to use with my own database tables but I couldn't. After run project I saw red error line on web.config custom membership provider line.   :(
`type="Mvc4ApplicationTest2.Models.CustomMembershipProvider"` I found article that said me to add below lines to web.config and I did.

```
add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"
add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"
```

Now application run :)  but after get to login page and clicked on submit i get to new error that hint me like this:

```
To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
```

Again I searched and I found some articles says me have to add prior line to web.config but with true value !!? `add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true"` 
I confused. ?(
So What can I do?  Can everyone please help me? 
and other question, I want to use the standard, strong and useful method to secure my web application. do you think if I must use websecurity classes or other approach?

Sincerely
Ali

Comment: It looks like your CustomMembershipProvider does not inherit from ExtendedMembershipProvider.

Comment: If you know please share me how can i do that to inherit from ExtendedMembershipProvider. it's abstract class. I can't find a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot and reading many articles I found it Finally. That is stupid mistake. I used to inherit from **System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider**. so I took error about needing **ExtendedMembershipProvider** implementation. So I did it with **WebMatrix.WebData.ExtendedMembershipProvider** and then every things were fine. Thanks for all advises and helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I registered my custom membership provider in the Web.config file of my MVC 4 project:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyCustomMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyCustomMembershipProvider" type="MyProject.MyCustomMembershipProvider, MyProject" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Note that "MyProject.MyCustomMembershipProvider" should be the fully qualified path to your membership class, and "MyProject" is the name of the assembly it is contained in (usually your project name).

Also be sure that your membership provider class extends the MembershipProvider, like so:

```
public class MyCustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    // Code here
}
```

I do not have the 'enableSimpleMembership' or 'autoFormsAuthentication' lines in my Web.config.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi Dear, Thanks for your heeds, My Method is like this: 
{ name="MyMembershipProvider"        type="Mvc4ApplicationTest2.Models.CustomMembershipProvider, Mvc4ApplicationTest2"           connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"   }
But after removing 'enableSimpleMembership' old error came back {This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage.} and story remain :(

Comment: @user1830909 What error message do you get? Also, [this article](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx) does a good job explaining how to create custom membership and role providers.

Comment: I said it up. the error is {This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage.} but some people advised to add {enableSimpleMembership} in web.config. that is solve this problem but raise other which get to this exception {To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".} and folish circular error has remain.

Comment: @user1830909 Try keeping the 'enableSimpleMembership' and 'autoFormsAuthentication' lines and add the following in the appSettings of your Web.config: `<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />`.

Comment: HTX9 please read my question again carefully. You drop me to one of two error cycle. please read slowly then if you have a useful solution advise me. Thanks.