# ASP.Net MVC 4 Generic Principal Difficulties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I am developing an **ASP.Net MVC 4** web application. Previously my MVC applications have been developed using **MVC 3** and with this new **MVC 4** application I have just copied/ reused my **authentication and authorisation code** from previous applications.

When a user logs into my site I do the following

**Account Controller**

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = _userService.GetUser(model.Email.Trim());

        //Create Pipe Delimited string to store UserID and Role(s)
        var userData = user.ApplicantID.ToString();

        foreach (var role in user.UserRoles)
        {
            userData = userData + "|" + role.description;
        }

        _formAuthService.SignIn(user.ApplicantFName, false, userData);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Portfolio");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

**FormsAuthenticationService**

```
public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService
{
    public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie, string UserData)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

        // Create and tuck away the cookie
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(15), createPersistentCookie, UserData);
        // Encrypt the ticket.
        string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        //// Create the cookie.
        HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Get the authentication cookie
    string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

    // If the cookie can't be found, don't issue the ticket
    if (authCookie == null) return;

    // Get the authentication ticket and rebuild the principal
    // & identity
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

    string[] UserData = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { '|' });

    GenericIdentity userIdentity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name);
    GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(userIdentity, UserData);
    Context.User = userPrincipal;

}
```

This code works well in my previous MVC 3 applications, but in this MVC 4 application, inside the Razor View, the following code does not seem to be accessing the **IsInRole** property to perform the role check

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Applicant"))
{
    <p>text</text>
}
```

Again, this worked perfectly in my MVC 3 applications.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions as to why this won't work with my MVC 4 application?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

**Extra Info**

My MVC 4 application is using .Net Framework 4.0

The screenshot below shows my **Generic Principal** which is assigned to **Context.User**. You can see that for this User, the **m_roles** contains two strings, the **UserID** (100170) and their **Role**(Applicant). But for some reason, The **IsInRoles** cannot be accessed or seen in my **MVC 4** Razor View, however, it could in my identical **MVC 3** Razor View.
[image]

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Folks

I finally resolved this issue. It appears by default the **SimpleMembershipProvider** is enabled when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application. I did not want to use the **SimpleMembershipProvider** on this occasion, however, I needed to disable it in my web config with the following line

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

My call to **User.IsInRole** works great now.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.  Not at all intuitive.

Comment: I upgraded a site from mvc3 to mvc4.  I didn't even have this key in the web.config but my principal wasn't correct.  Adding the above worked for me.  Why does it default to true even if the app setting key is missing...

Answer (score 4):

In MVC 4 you can access the `User` from the `WebPageRenderingBase`, so inside razor syntax you have direct access to the `User` instance:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Applicant"))
{
    <p>text</p>
}
```

I see that you are creating a `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and an `HttpCookie` manually. The FormsAuthentication class would do this for you using [`SetAuthCookie(string, bool[, string])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx). In this sense your auth service can be reduced to:

```
public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService
{
    public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie, string UserData)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }
}
```

It turns out you also need to change `Application_AuthenticateRequest` to `Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest`:

```
protected void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately it still does not work, the code in my Razor View, even with your suggestions still ignores the IsInRole check. Please help.

Comment: @tgriffiths You have configured/included this role in your asp.net administrative tool right? And the user you are testing appears to be in a such a role?

Comment: I figured it out with the help of this posthttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425163/create-custom-memebership-provider-in-mvc-4-always-get-error

Comment: @tgriffiths I found the same thing. I will update my answer with this.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC 4 **HttpContext.Current.User** is not exposed so you can't use it. What i did was create a custom BaseViewPage and added following code in it.

```
    public abstract class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
    {
        public virtual new Principal User
        {
            get { return base.User as Principal; }
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
    {
        public virtual new Principal User
        {
            get { return base.User as Principal; }
        }
    }
```

And then make following changes to *system.web.webPages.razor/pages* section your **web.config** in Views folder.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="WebApp.Views.BaseViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    ...
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Hope this solves your problem.