# MVC And Control Based Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

Is it possible to define authorization at control level ? If so what is the best practice ?

Consider I have input control named daily wages (text box). userRoleOne is an user role who supposed to see this field, other user roles should not see this field . what is the best practice to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Current instance of `HttpContext` is accessible in Razor's views by name `Context`, so you can check is user in role, or not:

```
@if (Context.User.IsInRole("userRoleOne"))
{
    Html.TextBox("dailyWages", "")
}
```

It should work without any additional code with `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` and Windows Authentication, but may not work with Forms Authentication and other memberships.

In last case you should manually create an object of `GenericPrincipal` class in  `Application_AuthenticateRequest` method of `Global.asax` (see [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772034/asp-net-mvc-4-generic-principal-difficulties)).